# Edit profile page for "10-million questions" event?

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page, 10m-questions-milestone

https://stackoverflow.com/10m has this suggestion (last line):

> Not a fan of teh twitters? No problem. Just add #SOreadytohelp to your
>   "About Me" on your profile page.

(I *am* not a fan of teh twitters.) But doing so looks ... ahem ... silly:
https://stackoverflow.com/users/939860/erwin-brandstetter?tab=profile

Any better options?

Even after fixing the format like [@gunr2171 suggested](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/302929/939860), it still seems odd that those among us who don't twitter have to add a twitter hashtag to the personal profile.

Comment: If you put a space before the `#` then the `#` shows correctly

Comment: \#SOreadytohelp if you want it non bolded

Comment: @nikoshr: but will it still do the job?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Ha, well, no idea:)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter welcome to social media, where things make little sense and people do it because everyone else is already doing it.

Comment: @gunr2171: and there I thought, we do things *right* on SO. :)

Comment: This would be avoided by a [CommonMark syntax requirement that balpha and Shog9 have argued against](http://talk.commonmark.org/t/heading-not-working/819).

Comment: "*Not a fan of teh twitters? No problem. Just add #SOreadytohelp to your "About Me" on your profile page.*" It seems you can do either or.

Comment: Came here to post the exact same issue! If I add the hashtag to my profile, do I still get entered in to the draw to win the free swag?

Comment: 'teh', surely that should be 'the'.  (I am not a fan of the twitters.)

Comment: @CodeUniquely: Nah, that seems to be on purpose.

Comment: Re 'teh': Because using misspelled definite articles before plurals of indefinite nouns is more teh funs than just using teh 'the'.

Comment: Well, to be honest it was so confusing the that "***teh***" that I was wondering if I'm misunderstanding that they mean twitter profile rather than SO profile! :-/

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Why is the URL dead?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you type the hashtag on a single line in your About Me section it will render as a html header. Putting a space before the hash makes the symbol appear.

## You don't want this

#This is what you want

```
#You don't want this

 #This is what you want
```

And for why Stack Exchange chose to use hashtags in your About Me, I don't know. It's a social media thing.

#DealWithIt

---

On a more serious note:

Hashtags are just temporary social media "tags", unique identifier to help filter out and categorize content. SE can easily find twitter messages using the provided hashtag, so they need something similar for SO profiles.

The pattern of a twitter hashtag is unique enough to not have already been used - so profiles containing it are easily searchable for the devs.

I mean, they could have used something else for SO profiles, but you might as well keep it uniform. This is, after all, a social media campaign.

How about we add a predefined guid to our profile! That's a programmer thing to do.

```
10 million questions! {434a403b-073d-458c-854c-0e5f89e9a758}
```

Comment: Tell me what we want, what we really, really want?

Comment: `NullReferenceException: object 'spiceGirls' has already been deallocated.`

Comment: I'll add just for you that guid to my profile :-D

Comment: If you're finding that this advice doesn't work, you're probably adding the indented hashtag after a bulleted list, as I was. There's [a workaround for this known gotcha here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266893/300836); basically you can insert an empty comment between the bullet list and the indented hashtag. (Also: if I'd known it was going to be *this* complicated, I'd just have tweeted in the first place...)

Comment: Maybe some 1500+ user can create a temporary [tag:SOreadytohelp] tag which MUST be used only in profile pages.

Answer (score 10):

Or you could just put that in a sentence:

like here #SOreadytohelp

Comment: Since I can't stop reading it as "So ready to help!" as in really ready to help, I added it as "I am #SOreadytohelp"

Comment: @Kitalda that may be the intent.

Answer (score 2):

Or add it as a code sample (prepending it with four spaces) and get a nice grey background...  Will it work better than the other suggestions? No idea!

https://stackoverflow.com/users/377341/stratosgear?tab=profile