# Code blocks in list items don't render correctly

Tags: support, markdown, markdown-rendering

I want to have a code block displayed as part of or after a list item.  However, the codeblock below a list item doesn't render as a code block.  How do I format a list and code block together?

Input:

```
- html

    <div id="panel_log"></div>

- css

    #panel_log {
      position:absolute;
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      border:1px solid #000;
      background-color:#fff;
      top:20px;
      left:20px;
      cursor:move;
    }
```

Output:

- html
- css

  ## panel_log {

  position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:#fff;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    cursor:move;
  }

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3793

Comment: But I don't want to nest, that's the thing

Comment: Then why are you using a list if you don't want most of the stuff to be in the list items?

Comment: I want a non-nested list (if possible)

Comment: So you want code immediately following a list item but you don't want the code in the list item?

Comment: Use an html comment between the bullet point and the code. If I remember correctly, that should fix it how you want it. (Though I think it would look better with the code nested in the list.)

Comment: the html comment <!-- --> doesn't improve a lot, if I've done what you meant

Comment: You'll want a blank line between the comment and the next bullet point. (I had meant putting the comment _above_ the code, my bad for not being clearer.) See [here.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266893/2607247)

Comment: Putting the answer in the question just makes the question confusing because it looks like you're saying that the "formatted with double spacing:" section is also wrong.

Comment: @BSMP you're right, I'll stop doing that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make the blocks part of the list items, indent them one more level.  One level of indentation on a list item indicates a continuation, so a continuation with a code block would be two levels.

```
* HTML

    <!-- language: lang-html -->

        <span class=stack-overflow></span>

* CSS

    <!-- language: lang-css -->

        .stack-overflow {
        }
```

- HTML

  ```html
  <span class=stack-overflow></span>
  ```
- CSS

  ```css
  .stack-overflow {
  }
  ```

Unlike the example below, the comments here are indented, so they are considered as part of the list item block, not as a separator.

---

If you want the blocks *outside* the list items then a) you're not really using a list for its intended purpose and b) add a comment to invisibly separate the blocks.

```
* JavaScript

<!-- language: lang-javascript -->

    console.log('Stack Overflow');

* Output

<!-- break -->

    'Stack Overflow'
```

- JavaScript

```javascript
console.log('Stack Overflow');
```

- Output

```
'Stack Overflow'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use actual `ul` and `li` tags to keep the code from being inside the list item. Just close the list before you add your code.

- html

```
<div id="panel_log"></div>
```

- css

```
#panel_log {
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  background-color:#fff;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
  cursor:move;
}
```

But you'd be doing folks a favor if you just used the runnable snippet instead:

```css
#panel_log {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  cursor: move;
}
```

```html
<div id="panel_log"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<breaking_the_rules/>` Using this as I need the markup to ask the OP a question

What would you prefer to have with the folowing text?

```
- html

    <div id="panel_log"></div>

- css

    #panel_log {
      position:absolute;
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      border:1px solid #000;
      background-color:#fff;
      top:20px;
      left:20px;
      cursor:move;
    }
```

Would you like

- html

  ```
  <div id="panel_log"></div>
  ```
- css

  ```
  #panel_log {
    position:absolute;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:#fff;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    cursor:move;
  }
  ```

Or

- html

```
<div id="panel_log"></div>
```

- css

```
#panel_log {
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  background-color:#fff;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
  cursor:move;
}
```